# Trying to send json object in alamofire but it's going in a json array

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I want my json request to be like:

```
{
"business_id": 1,
    "images": [{
        "image": "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"
    }, {
        "image": "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"
    }]
}
```

i.e it is going as an array, i want it as a json object.

I am sending my parameters as:

```
let parameter = ["business_id" : business.id  , "images" : business.imagearray ] as [String : Any]
```

And here is the code through which i am sending my request:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters:parameter  , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: Request.headers())
```

Appending images to image arraay:

```
   for img in imageArraaay { 
var dic = Dictionary<String, String>() dic = ["image":imgg] as Dictionary }
 let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: myNewDictionary, options: []) as AnyObject 
business.imageArray = NSString(data: jsonData as! Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! 
imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

I know i am making some mistake, I am new to IOS so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore how is that relevant to the question?

Comment: try  this params
       `let params = ["business_id": "1", "images":[["image":"base64","image":"base46"]]] as [String : Any]`

Comment: @phadteviraj It would be good if u edit this question and include this in it in proper format

Comment: @a.masri I want the image array to be dynamic, so how can that be done using your method?

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore now could you please check

Comment: try this 
       `var imagesList = [[String:String]]()
   
        imagesList.append(["image":"base64"])
        imagesList.append(["image":"base64"])
        let params = ["business_id": "1", "images":imagesList] as [String : Any]`

Comment: i have tried what your above code but its giving me array of array rather then array of dictionaries ....even i tried to do it as array of dictionaries.. here what im  getting as a

Comment: @a.masri i have tried what your above code but its giving me array of array rather then array of dictionaries ....even i tried to do it as array of dictionaries.. here what im  getting as .                                                                          [ ["image": "base64"],  ["image":"base64"]  ] what i want is                             [{"image":"base64"} , {"image" : "base64"}] this array will be directly given to key value pair in paramters while making request

Comment: @phadteviraj based on your json object you want to send json array in json object that's what I did

Comment: If you want to be sure of style json   try this code under declaration params  
`if let theJSONData = try?  JSONSerialization.data(
      withJSONObject: params,
      options: .prettyPrinted
      ),
      let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData,
                               encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) {
          print("JSON string = \n\(theJSONText)")
    }
  }`

Comment: @a.masri yep after doing serialization im trying to send serialized data in my request call. but its giving me extra argument in code error fr request.

Comment: @phadteviraj
You've done the wrong thing ،You should send the Params to your request

Comment: try same this https://iswift.org/playground?34DHKF&v=3

Comment: @a.masri i tried your method but im getting this error                                                   responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength) ...in encoding im sending URLEncoding.default here is my code which i implemented  business.id = 1
        let parameter = ["business_id" : business.id  , "images" : imagePara] as [String : Any]
        print(parameter)

Comment: @a.masri  fixed it code is working thanks a lot

Comment: please add correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Possibly This should Work for you:

```
    let imageArray = ["iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg12345","iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHgAAACCCAYAAAC6789"] //Dummy content
    print(imageArray)

    var ImgParam = [[String:String]]()

    for img in imageArray {
        print(img)
        ImgParam.append(["image":img])
    }
    print(ImgParam)

    let parameter = ["business_id" : 1 , "images" : ImgParam ] as [String : Any]
    print(parameter)
```

Comment: i tried your method but im getting this error                                                   responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength) ...in encoding im sending URLEncoding.default here is my code which i implemented  business.id = 1
        let parameter = ["business_id" : business.id  , "images" : imagePara] as [String : Any]
        print(parameter)


//request
  Alamofire.request(url, method:.post, parameters: parameter , encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: Request.headers())

Comment: You are using POST or GET method.?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic to append base64 data into imageAarray:

```
var encodedString = String()                                             
let imageData : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0) as! NSData
encodedString = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
var baseDataDictionary = Dictionary<String , String>()
baseDataDictionary.updateValue(encodedString, forKey: "image")  
imagesList.append(baseDataDictionary) // imageList is array of dictionaries
```

Here how I pass parameters and fire request:

```
let parameter = ["business_id" : businessId , "images" : imageList] as [String : Any]
     Alamofire.request(url, method:.post, parameters: parameter , encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: Request.headers())
```